# Why does /(red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green') return ["red", "red"]?

Tags: javascript, regex

In my javascript console I typed 
`/(red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green')`

And it returned an array with two results: 
`["red", "red"]`

Shouldn't it return an array with 4 results? As in:
`["red", "green", "red", "green"]`?

Comment: note, `g` in exec, use match instead of `exec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `exec` works is by returning an array* of results AND modifying the regex object.
<sub>*) returns null if no match found.</sub>

The returned array contains the entire matched string at index 0, and 1 entry per matched group.

In your example, the returned result is:
`[0]` = `"red"` <-- The entire match
`[1]` = `"red"` <-- The match for the first group

For example, the next snippet returns THE SAME RESULT:

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(/(red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green, red, green, red, green')))
```

And the next one returns an array with 3 entries (Whole match, 2 groups):

```js
alert(JSON.stringify(/(red|green), (red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green, red, green, red, green')))
```

Comment: This was the clearest, easiest to follow explanation that gave two different examples to show how .exec() works.

Comment: Although alerting the second example (e.g. converting it to a string) makes it harder to understand that the actual returned result is an array of length 2 as such: /(red|green), (red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green, red, green, red, green') returns ["red, green", "red", "green"]

Answer (score 5):

As the comment states you want the string method match:

```
> 'red, green, red, green'.match(/(red|green)/g)
["red", "green", "red", "green"]
```

Comment: The question is `Why does /(red|green)/g.exec('red, green, red, green') return [“red”, “red”]?`

Comment: Your statement is correct and useful, but Amit's and Tushar's better explain why I was getting the result I was.

Answer (score 4):

The [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns only the **first** match even if you specify `g` global flag.

> The exec() method executes a search for **a** match in a specified string. Returns a result array, or null.

Because the first element in the `array` is the **complete match string** and second element of the `array` is the **capturing group** which is enclosed inside `()` in the `regex`.

If you try this regex:

```
/(red|green),/g.exec('red, green, red, green')
```

You'll get

```
["red,", "red"]
```

Comment: complete match? where?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? This is absolutely correct; the result set is the full pattern match followed by the capture group. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: And please don't use code formatting for words that aren't code. "array" and "regex" are not code.

Comment: @Tushar op's regex capture and match same set of strings. Your explanation is wrong. There is something with `g` in `exec` function.

Comment: @AvinashRaj `Because the first element in the array is the complete match string and second param of the array is the matching group which is enclosed inside () in the regex.` see this. let me know if anything is wrong. Also, check the example given

Comment: @AvinashRaj `/(red|green),\s+\w+/g.exec('red, green, red, green')` execute this in `console`

Comment: @Tushar you mean `red` alone a complete match? Then what about `green` ? And don't use any other examples than op's.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The `regex` `(red|green)` says red OR green

Comment: ya, `red` or `green` **globally**.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following string and regex

```
var str = "red, green, red, green";
var re = /(red|green)/g;
```

With [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```
var m;
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log(m);
}
```

Output:

```
["red", "red"]
["green", "green"]
["red", "red"]
["green", "green"]
```

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis

and

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec() method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec))

---

With [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
console.log( str.match(re) );
```

Output:

```
["red", "green", "red", "green"]
```